# Check if MDM server is connected

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, persistence, mdm

We have an app that needs to read from `com.apple.configuration.managed` when it is installed from our MDM server, JAMF. This works perfectly fine.

The problem scenario is:

The data MDM data persists if a user downloads the app from JAMF, uninstalls, then reinstalls from TestFlight or the AppStore. When the user reinstalls from TestFlight or the AppStore, the app still reads the old data from `com.apple.configuration.managed`.

Is there a way to check if the device is actually connected to an MDM server? That way it won't read from the configuration profile if it's not

Answer (score 1):

Many of the MDM vendors have iOS SDKs that you can add to your app that will allow the app to communicate with the MDM and verify whether the device is enrolled. I do not have any experience with JAMF and a quick Google search did not return anything promising.

Some of the MDM vendors have gotten creative in how their App SDK communicates with the MDM to identify the device that the app is running on now that iOS 7 makes it impossible for the app to obtain the device's UDID.

That being said, the best solution I can think of would be to have the MDM push down the device's UDID to the app in the managed config (`com.apple.configuration.managed`) and then use a web service call back to the MDM to query whether the device is currently enrolled.

Then in your app you would simply check for the existence of the managed config, and if it exists pull out the UDID and make a web service call to your MDM to determine whether the device is enrolled.